# Cannot close a script-opened window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

This JS works okay on Chrome but not on Firefox, new window cannot be closed from JS:

```
function print(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var printWindow = window.open();
    var printHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
        + "<html lang='en'>"
        + "<meta charset='UTF-8'>"
        + "<title>Printing the canvas</title>"
        + "<style type='text/css' media='print'>"
        + "@page{size:auto; margin:0mm auto 0mm auto;} h1{text-align:center; font:10mm Arial, sans-serif;}"
        + "</style>"
        + "<script>"
        + "window.onafterprint = function(){ window.close(); };"
        + "</script>"
        + "<body>"
        + "<br><h1>My canvas</h1>"
        + "<br><img onload='print();' src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>"
        + "</body>"
        + "</html>";
    printWindow.document.write(printHtml);
}
```

Firefox supposedly allows window.close() on windows which were opened by JS but this does not work for me.

Comment: It can only be closed by the script that opened it. So the original script can call `printWindow.close()`, but the code running in the window can't use `window.close()`.

Comment: BTW, don't name your function `print()`, as that overrides the built-in `window.print()`.

Comment: you can use `Window.postMessage()` for sending message from new window and then close from main thread

Comment: Barmar, printWindow.close() was my first version of code but did not work on Firefox. Sorry, real function name is not print(), I just translated it to english for simplicity's sake :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Window.postMessage()` event like this:

```
// main window
const w = window.open('MY_WINDOW_URL')
w.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    if (e.data === 'timeToClose') w.close();
})

// window
function print(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var printWindow = window.open();
var printHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    + "<html lang='en'>"
    + "<meta charset='UTF-8'>"
    + "<title>Printing the canvas</title>"
    + "<style type='text/css' media='print'>"
    + "@page{size:auto; margin:0mm auto 0mm auto;} h1{text-align:center; font:10mm Arial, sans-serif;}"
    + "</style>"
    + "<script>"
    + "window.onafterprint = function(){ window.postMessage('timeToClose'); };"
    + "</script>"
    + "<body>"
    + "<br><h1>My canvas</h1>"
    + "<br><img onload='print();' src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>"
    + "</body>"
    + "</html>";
printWindow.document.write(printHtml);
```

}

Comment: In caller script, printWindow.onafterprint = function(){ printWindow.close(); }; onafterprint routine does get executed but window won't close in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

With a small variation it works in firefox

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
       <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>ΤΙΤΛΟΣ</title>
       </head>
    
       <body style="background-color: burlywood;">
          <div>
             <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
          </div>
          <button onclick="myPrint()">open window</button>
          <script>
             const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
             const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
             ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    
              function myPrint() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
                var printWindow = window.open()
                var printHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>"
                   + "<html lang='en'>"
                   + "<meta charset='UTF-8'>"
                   + "<title>Printing the canvas</title>"
                   + "<style type='text/css' media='print'>"
                   + "@page{size:auto; margin:0mm auto 0mm auto;} h1{text-align:center; font:10mm Arial, sans-serif;}"
                   + "</style>"
                   + "<script>"
                   + "function aaa(){setTimeout(()=>{document.getElementById('closer').click()},1)}"
                   + "</" + "script>"
                   + "<body onafterprint = 'aaa()'>"
                   + "<br><h1>My canvas</h1>"
                   + "<br><img onload='print()'; src='" + canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>"
                   + "<button id='closer' onclick='window.close()' hidden></button>"
                   + "</body>"
                   + "</html>" 
             printWindow.document.write(printHtml);
          }
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```